# How to Read db.properties File from WEB-INF

Tags: java, file

I am  using netbeans. I want to read db.properties file from WEB-INF Folder. But it return null;

```
InputStream input = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("db.properties");   // returning null

InputStream input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/db.properties"); // returning null.
```

But when I put my db.properties file int Web_INF/classes above code work fine.

the following code throws File not found in both cases. (in Web-INF/db.properties and in Web-INF/classes/db.properties).

```
FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(new File("db.properties")); //throws exception
```

Any Clue.

```
package com.towertech.db;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;
  import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.*;

public class DataSource 
{
    PoolProperties poolProperties;
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource datasource;
    ClassLoader classLoader;
    InputStream input;
    FileInputStream fileInput;
    Properties properties;

public org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource getDatasource() {
    return datasource;
}

public void setDatasource(org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource datasource) {
    this.datasource = datasource;
}

public DataSource() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    input = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/db.properties");
    input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/db.properties");
    fileInput = new FileInputStream(new File("/WEB-INF/db.properties"));
    if(input == null)
        properties.load(fileInput);  
    else
        properties.load(input);  
    poolProperties = new PoolProperties();
    poolProperties.setDbProperties(properties);
    datasource.setPoolProperties(poolProperties);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    DataSource ds = new DataSource();
    System.out.println(ds.toString());

}

public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException
{
    return datasource.getConnection();
}

public void returnConnection(Connection con) throws SQLException
{
    con.close();
}    
}
```

Comment: Are u using servlets ? or Spring controller ? any other ?

Comment: I am using Spring web Service

Comment: This is called from controller or service ? I mean DataSource class, from where/how it will be invoked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read properties file under `WEB-INF` inside the Spring controller using the  `servletcontext` object as shown below:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

   @RequestMapping(value="/myMapping")
   public R myMethod(HttpServletRequest request, ...) {

      //Get the servletcontext from request
      InputStream input = request.getSession().getServletContext().
             getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/db.properties");

     //read properties

   }   
}
```